# "the deep" vs "the depths"

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between `deep` (as a noun) and `depths`? Since `deep` is primarily an adjective, when one would use it rather than `depths`?

From what I see `the deep` (always with `the` and in singular) refers specifically to the oceanic depths. (Though, I am not sure if it is the only meaning/difference.)

Comment: "The deep" is sometimes used as an idiom (without specifying "the deep *what*") to refer to the deepest part of the ocean (real or metaphoric).  In this sense it is roughly interchangeable with "the depths of the ocean" (though "the deep" is much more poetic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The deep* is a metaphoric name for the ocean.  *Depths* are very low places in general.  You may sink to the **depths of the ocean,** but also **the depths of the earth** and **the depths of despair**.